# Using Javascript to dynamically add Django formsets

Tags: javascript, html, django

I'm trying to implement [this django snippet](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1389/) into my code. the instructions state to "Handle the 'click' event for your add and delete buttons", but I'm new to using Javascript and am having a hard time figuring out the last configuration step.

Here's what I've got:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block base_content %}

<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/dynamic-formset.js"></script>
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jquery.formset.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $(".inline.{{ serial_form.prefix }}").formset({
            prefix: "{{ serial_form.prefix }}",
        })
        $(".inline.{{ part_form.prefix }}").formset({
            prefix: "{{ part_form.prefix }}",
        })
    })
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('.add-row').click(function() {
        return addForm(this, 'form');
    });
    $('.delete-row').click(function() {
        return deleteForm(this, 'form');
    })
})
</script>

<div class="content">

<h1>Create new tool:</h1>

</div>

<div>

<form method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<table>
{% for field in form %}
    {% if field.label != "Old control number" %}
        <tr><td>{{ field.label_tag }}:</td><td>{{ field }}</td></tr>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{{ serial_form.management_form }}
{{ serial_form.non_form_errors }}
{% for form in serial_form %}
    <tr class="dynamic-form">
        <td>{{ form.label_tag }}</td>
        <td>{{ form }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
<tr>
<td colspan="4"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="add-row"> 
Add another serial number</a></td></tr>

{{ part_form.management_form }}
{{ part_form.non_form_errors }}
{% for form in part_form %}
    <tr><td>{{ form.label_tag }}</td><td>{{ form }}</td></tr>
{% endfor %}

</table>
<input type="submit" value="Save new tool calibration">
</form>

</div>

{% endblock %}
```

I know I'm close but I'm unsure on how to do the last bit of configuration. Any and all help is appreciated. Thanks!